# guzzle/guzzle to guzzlehttp/guzzle with laravel

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I had setup `intervention/imagecache` and this package need to `guzzlehttp/guzzle` and i was setup `weboap/visitor` and this package need to `guzzle/guzzle` (the old version of `guzzlehttp/guzzle`)

si have problem with using `composer update`

it's say:

```
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
```

can any help?

Comment: `weboap/visitor` has no direct or indirect dependency on the old `guzzle/guzzle`. Run `composer why guzzle/guzzle` to show a list of dependencies in your application that use the old Guzzle. Try to update these packages to get rid of the old Guzzle.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I installed the new guzzlehttp client but I cannot make the error go away